# Random arrays in k-means algorithm

Tags: c#

I am working on k-means algorithm and I have found some codes from: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/12/01/k-means-data-clustering-using-c.aspx, but I want to change this code’s array to the [100,10] array which is generated randomly.
Any help appreciated,

Comment: Not clear enough , can you specified which point do you want to change exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();
double[][] rawData =
    Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(j =>
            (double)random.Next(250)
        ).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();
```